# Paginate through a randomized list of blog posts using will_paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, random, will-paginate

I want to give users the ability to page through my blog posts in random order.

I can't implement it like this:

```
@posts = Post.paginate :page => params[:page], :order => 'RANDOM()'
```

since the `:order` parameter is called with every query, and therefore I risk repeating blog posts.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RAND accepts a seed in MySQL:

```
RAND(N)
```

From the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand):

> RAND(), RAND(N)
>
> Returns a random floating-point value
>   v in the range 0 <= v < 1.0. If a
>   constant integer argument N is
>   specified, it is used as the seed
>   value, which produces a repeatable
>   sequence of column values. In the
>   following example, note that the sequences of values produced by RAND(3) is the same both places where it occurs.

Other databases should have similar functionality.

If you use the **SAME** seed each time you call RAND, the order will be consistent across requests and you can paginate accordingly.

You can then store the seed in the user's session - so each user will see a set of results unique to them.

Comment: What's the syntax for using RANDOM() with a seed? I can't find it.

Comment: Added syntax details for MySQL

Answer (score 1):

To avoid each page (generated from a new request) potentially having a repeated post you'll need to store the order of posts somewhere for retrieval over multiple requests.

If you want each user to have a unique random order then save the order in a session array of IDs.

If you don't mind all users having the same random order then have a position column in the posts table.

Answer (score 0):

You could :order => RANDOM() on your original query that populates @posts, and then when you paginate, don't specify the order.

Answer (score -2):

Create a [named scope](http://railscasts.com/episodes/108-named-scope) on your Post model that encapsulates the random behaviour:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  named_scope :random, :order => 'RANDOM()'
  .
  .
  .
end
```

Your `PostsController` code then becomes:

```
@posts = Post.random.paginate :page => params[:page]
```

Comment: This won't work -- you'll get a random 30 (or however big your page size is) posts every time.