# Rails 3, will_paginate, random, repeating records, Postgres, setseed failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, random, will-paginate

I have a database of movies with attributes. I'd like to return a queried batch of those movies in random order to a template with pagination. I'm using will_paginate. I tried the following:

```
## MoviesController

movies = Movie.get_movies(query_string)   # a method in Movie model that takes in 
                                          # a query_string and fetches movies 
                                          # with user-set params

@movies = movies.order('random()').page(params[:page]).per_page(16)
```

This works nicely, except movies are repeated from page to page. Solutions to this problem have been posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395418/rails-random-activerecord-while-paginating) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/810267/paginate-through-a-randomized-list-of-blog-posts-using-will-paginate). Those links explain that, because the **random()** seed is reset from page to page, there is no consistency and **OFFSET** is rendered useless. They offer great solutions for MySQL users, as its **rand(n)** function takes a seed **n**. Postgres, however, doesn't do this. You have to declare **setseed(n)** in **SELECT** before issuing  **random()** in **ORDER**.

So I tried the postgres way to set the seed:

```
@movies = movies.select('setseed(.5)').order('random()').page(params[:page]).per_page(16)
```

Curiously, that returned Movie objects with absolutely no attributes. The following was raised from the template:

> ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError in Movies#action
>
> > missing attribute: some_movie_attribute

I debugged this and, once the stack reached action_controller/metal, @movies contained:

`[#<Movie >, #<Movie >, #<Movie >, #<Movie >, #<Movie >, #<Movie >, #<Movie >, #<Movie >, #<Movie >, #<Movie >, #<Movie >, #<Movie >, #<Movie >, #<Movie >, #<Movie >, #<Movie >]`

That number of Movie objects (18) corresponds to the number of movies returned from the query.

I also tried the following to see if **setseed(n)** was the problem by removing the random order method:

```
@movies = movies.select('setseed(.5)').page(params[:page]).per_page(16)
```

This returned the same non-attribute Movie objects as layed out above. So it appears that **setseed(n)** is indeed the issue.

I tried a couple of workarounds, like:

```
# MoviesController

movies = Movie.get_movies(query_string)
shuf_movs = movies.shuffle  ## effectively turns shuf_movs into an array

@movies = shuf_movs.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 16)
```

That also returned pages with repeating movies. I thought this was because pagination needed the objects to be ordered by *something*, and you can't set seeds in Array#shuffle. So I tried writing my own randomization code that would temporarily store an id to be ordered by in the Movie objects. (Please excuse the sloppy code):

```
# Movie model

attr_accessor :rand_id

# MoviesController

movies = get_movies(query_string)
movies_count = movies.count
r = Random.new
nums = []
rand_movs = []
id = 1
while nums.count != movies_count
  num = r.rand(0..movies_count - 1)
  if !(nums.include?(num))
    movie = movies[num]
    movie.rand_id = id
    rand_movs << movie
    nums      << num
    id += 1
  end
end

@movies = rand_movs.sort_by { |a| a.rand_id }.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 16)
```

That still produced repeating movies in different pages. At this point I realize will_paginate doesn't take in what you've sorted by before **paginate** is called. So I tried this:

```
@movies = rand_movs.paginate(:order => 'rand_id', :page => params[:page], :per_page => 16)
```

That still repeats records. **:order -> 'rand_id'** is ignored because **:order** only matters when you're dealing with ActiveRecord objects, not arrays.

So **setseed(n)** appears to be my only hope for achieving randomized non-repeating records using will_paginate. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: The select specifies the columns in the query, and you specified none, only the seed. Not sure if it will work, but try this: `.select('*, setseed(1)')`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Not a postgres person but ... I'd try

```
Movie.connection.execute "select setseed(0.5)"
Movie.where(...).order('random()').page(params[:page]).per_page(15)
```

With regards to `Array#shuffle` not taking a seed, it uses `Kernel.rand` so you can seed it using `Kernel.srand`

Comment: Thanks, Frederick. This did the trick. Also, thanks for the heads up re: seeding Array#shuffle with Kernel.

Comment: I am trying to achieve the same. This gives me the same random order on each reload, but how do I get a new random order for each user visiting the site?

Comment: You'd want to pass a different seed for each user

Comment: We had lots of issues about setseed randomly not returning the same random order. We found that switching to hash function would lead to more predictable results as mentioned in this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/56650710/943119

Answer (score 1):

try passing an array of fields to `select`:

```
@movies = movies.select(['setseed(.5)', 'some_movie_attribute']).order('random()').page(params[:page]).per_page(16)
```

Some result is using `some_movie_attribute`, which isn't being selected by your query, and so isn't available. Adding it as one of the select fields should resolve this one.

Comment: Thanks much. I tried `movies.select(['setseed(.5)', '*']).order('random()').page(params[:page]).per_page(16)
` Passing an array like you suggested, but rather with '*' to call all Movie fields (my template calls a bunch of attributes), renders the template (hooray!). But now with the seed set, the records don't order randomly - they're ordered by id no matter what seed is passed in. :-(

Comment: `.select`, at least in Rails/ActiveRecord 5.0.7.2 and 6.1.4.1 I tested (and probably some earlier versions as well), filters out the usage of `setseed`, but the [approved answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10370640/3310560) works well (as it uses `.execute` straightforward)