# Pagination with Postgres - avoid repeating items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination

I am attempting to paginate a list of items using a Postgres database, but am struggling to avoid having the items repeat on each page. I have been trying to integrate the 'setseed()' function, but have been unable to make it work. Below is my code:

```
@listings = Listing.find_by(approved_and_not_expired).select(['setseed(.5)', '*']).order('random()').page(params[:page]).per(items_loaded)
```

Comment: Probable duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10367690/rails-3-will-paginate-random-repeating-records-postgres-setseed-failure

Comment: This was the original line of code:  @listings = Listing.find_by(approved_and_not_expired).order('random()').page(params[:page]).per(items_loaded)

Comment: You probably do need `setseed`. The linked question solves exactly what you're asking about - pagination when doing a random ordering without repeats.

Comment: I was aware of the linked question/response, but wasn't entirely understanding the required use of Kernel.rand

Comment: `Kernel.rand/srand` was mentioned because the OP of that question was using `Array#shuffle`, which you are not.

Comment: The items are still repeating though.  There is something I am missing...

Comment: This is the current code in my Listings controller:
    Listing.connection.execute "select setseed(0.5)"
    @listings = Listing.find_by(approved_and_not_expired).select(['setseed(.5)', '*']).order('random()').page(params[:page]).per(items_loaded)

Comment: Shouldn't be adding `setseed` to the second line. Look closely at the top answer.

Comment: copied code from the wrong stage of its development.  I have it working now, but using the same seed means the listings display the same way ever time.  How do I create a random order, since setseed() doesn't accept a variable..

Comment: Cache the seed for awhile, and refresh it every so often, or something like that. You're not going to be able to get completely randomized results every single load without repeats. Subsequent pages need to use the same seed as the first page to avoid repeats, so you have to use the same seed for some amount of time/requests.