# How do you get Will_paginate to display pages correctly for a shuffled array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate

Im currently using will_paginate in Rails 3.1 to paginate an array as such

In the controller for #show

```
 @items = ["item1", "item2", "item3" ....... "item100"]

 @items.shuffle!
 @items.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
```

The problem i am facing is that each page looks completely different, ie different sequence of items, each time it is viewed. For example page 1 will show a different set if you view page 2 and click previous to go back to page 1. I am sure this is because of the shuffle in the controller. It seems that a new array is generated on each page view. Is there a way round this? Possibly storing the current @items in a session?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10367690/rails-3-will-paginate-random-repeating-records-postgres-setseed-failure

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 @items ||= ["item1", "item2", "item3" ....... "item100"].shuffle!
 @items.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
```